# Where will I clear customs traveling from US to Greece and back via Toronto?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration

I am traveling from US to Greece via Canada.  Where do I have to clear customs?
Flying from US to Toronto, Canada then off to Athens, Greece.  Then Greece to Toronto and then the US.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  I am not sure how to understand your question or even what your question actually is.  You normally will go through customs every time you enter the country.  US-Canada crossing might be different for the flights where you preclear for the US on Canadian side.

Comment: This might be a good question for your airline, especially as to whether you are  going to be going through Canada customs either or both directions. But you'll clear Greek customs in Greece and US customs either in Toronto or in the first US city you land in.

Answer (score 4):

When you fly out of the US the customs are always at the destination, so you will go through customs in Greece since you are most likely will be transiting through Canada.

On the way back you will preclear for the [US in Toronto](http://ask.metafilter.com/158794/Flying-from-USCanada-wheres-customs).